# VS2017 - General tab missing in Tools > Options > Test

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I go to Tools > Options > Test, I only get a Logging tab. How do I get the General tab to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason my computer had the Community version of VS2017 installed along with the Enterprise version, but it was defaulting to the Community version which has limited access to Testing options.